A Diophantine equation that is unsolved on a French forum
I come to share a difficult question posed in a French forum, and all attempts to solve the question have failed. Is there an angle of attack that has not been explored by the members of the said forum? Thank you for sharing ideas to solve the question.

Question :  prove that the equation $10(x^7 + y^7 + z^7) = 7(x^2 +
   y^2 + z^2)(x^5 + y^5 + z^5)$ has no solution if x, y, and z are
in $\mathbb Z$ such that $x + y + z ≠ 0.$

ADD A proposal  demonstration by YvesM from the French forum lesmathematiques.net
https://les-mathematiques.net/vanilla/discussion/comment/2513451#Comment_2513451

This web site is more aimed at research questions rather than competition problems. So your posting is off topic here.

This is not a competition question; I am asking for unexplored ideas to solve the problem.

Though it is certainly valid to ask about new ideas to solve a problem, usually successful such questions involve some more motivation of what gives them an interesting research angle than "unsolved on a French forum."

@Anthony solving this might well involve research-grade ideas. See for instance Bogdan Grechuk's questions on Diophantine equations. But I agree with LSpice that some motivation will help.

@DavidRoberts  I see this sort of thing sometimes on MSE...if $s_n = x^n + y^n + z^n$  there are relations  among $s_2, s_3, s_5$   and then $s_2, s_5, s_7$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5010776/contradictions-with-newtons-sums

@WillJagy I'm not active there, this may well be a standard Olympiad-style question. Not being either a number theorist or a old IMO participant, I can't judge the level that well.

"Is it recommended that I delete the question since it is off-topic for this site?" (added in an edit after closure) I removed this since would rather be a fit in MetaMO, or maybe just here in comments.

I'm voting to reopen. While a motivation would be nice, the equation has enough symmetry to feel naturalish. And it doesn't seem to have any very obvious solution.

Thank you for reopening the thread.

The nontrivial irreducible component of this projective curve has genus 7. Maybe someone can compute the quotient of this curve by the group of symmetries in $x,y,z$.

@FrançoisBrunault that's how Genocchi proved the case n=7 of "Fermat's Last Theorem".  In that case the quotient had rank zero.  If the rank is positive in this case, well we have more tools now than Genocchi did in the mid-1800's.

@FrançoisBrunault By setting $ s_1 = x + y + z $, $ s_2 = xy + yz + zx$, $ s_3 = xyz $, it was shown on the forum that the equation is equivalent to
$s_1 \big( 3s_1^6 - 21s_1^4s_2 + 35s_1^3s_3 + 35s_1^2s_2^2 - 105s_1s_2s_3 + 70s_3^2 \big) = 0.$

Continuing from @Noname we get the curve $s_1 = 0$ and a residual curve that is rational (this can be seen by dehomogenizing with $s_1 = 1$).  Next question is what are the intermediate curves between this rational curve and the top genus-7 curve.

It is quadratic in $s_3$, if you take a discriminant, you get $11 s_1^4 - 42 s_1^2 s_2 + 35 s_2^2=35 t^2$. This in turn is a ternary quadratic form in $s_1^2,s_2,t$ with easily parametrized solutions. Denoting $s_1^2=7u$ (this $u$ is an integer), we get $77u^2-42 us_2+5s_2^2=5t^2$, $(5t)^2=(5s_2-21u)^2+56u^2$, so, $56u^2$ is a difference of two squares.

Thank you for these new ideas; I will dive into them.

I computed the quotient curves with respect to the transpositions (permuting the variables), and we get a genus 2 curve with rank of the Jacobian equal to 2, so usual Chabauty doesn't work, but quadratic Chabauty could work. The quotient with respect to the 3-cicle is a genus 3 curve, hyperelliptic. Magma says the rank of the Jacobian is between 0 and 1, the 2-Selmer group is  Z/2 + Z/2 and I suspect the torsion is 6. It should be possible to use Chabauty if we know a point in the Jacobian of infinite order, or to proof the rank is in fact 0, and we compute the torsion.

Explícitly, the hyperelliptic genus 3 curve si the one defined by equation $Y^2=-7(X+1)(4X-1)(4X^6 + 36X^5 - 264X^4 + 424X^3 - 244X^2 + 2403X - 633)$, and one should prove that the set of rational points is given only by the Weierstrass points with $Y=0$, so $X=-1,1/4$.

https://les-mathematiques.net/vanilla/discussion/comment/2512335/#Comment_2512335

Since a member of the French forum has identified a calculation error in Fedor Petrov's suggestion, we should further explore Noam D. Elkies' idea.

@Noname what exactly is the calculation error in my calculation and what we get if not making an error?

@FedorPetrov In the linked comment the poster seems to aver that $(5t)^2=(5s_2-21u)^2+56u^2$ has a sign error, and the last plus sign should be a minus sign.

@R.P. Indeed, but still $56u^2$ is a difference of two squares

@FedorPetrov We cannot conclude; you can see the reason here.https://les-mathematiques.net/vanilla/discussion/comment/2512361/#Comment_2512361

EDIT: There was an error in my original argument. This is no longer an answer, but just a long comment.
Following Elkies and Xarles's suggestions, the quotient of this curve by a permutation of the variables of order $3$ is a genus $3$ hyperelliptic curve, whose model I will take to be
$$
C : y^{2} = x(140x^{6} - 18620x^{5} + 156800x^{4} - 548800x^{3} + 994700x^{2} - 948395x + 384160).
$$
(I checked this curve is isomorphic to the model given by Xarles in the comments, and it comes from moving one of the two Weierstrass points to infinity.) It suffices to show that the only rational points on this curve are the rational point at infinity and $(x,y) = (0,0)$. This implies the claim, because the preimages on the original curve of these two points are $(-1 : 0 : 1)$, $(0 : -1 : 1)$ and $(-1 : 1 : 0)$, all of which satisfy $x+y+z = 0$.
If there were a rational point on this curve with $x=a/b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then we obtain
$$
  (b^{4} y)^{2} = ab (140a^{6} - 18620a^{5}b + 156800a^{4}b^{2} - 548800a^{3}b^{3} + 994700a^{2}b^{4} - 948395ab^{5} + 384160b^{6}).
$$
Assume that $a \ne 0$ and set $d_{1} = ab$ and $d_{2} = 140a^{6} - \cdots + 384160b^{6}$. Then $d_{1} d_{2}$ is a square, and the only prime divisors $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ can have in common are divisors of $140 = 2^{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ and $384160 = 2^{5} \cdot 5 \cdot 7^{4}$. It follows that there is $\delta \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 7, \pm 10, \pm 14, \pm 35, \pm 70 \}$ for which $d_{1} = \delta c^{2}$ and $d_{2} = \delta e^{2}$ for some $c, e \in \mathbb{Z}$. Plugging in $b = \frac{\delta c^{2}}{a}$ into $d_{2} = \delta e^{2}$ gives rise to a genus $5$ hyperelliptic curve (of the form $Y^{2} = P(X)$ for $\deg(P) = 12$). The only $\delta$ for which these hyperelliptic curves have local points everywhere are $\delta \in \{ -2, -7, 10, 35 \}$. For $\delta = -2$ and $\delta = -7$, the curves have no real points. For $\delta = 10$, this genus $5$ curve maps to the genus $2$ hyperelliptic curve
$$
  y^{2} = 10 (140 x^{6} - 18620 x^{5} + \cdots + 384160)
$$
and the Jacobian of this curve has rank $1$. Hence Chabauty's method can be applied to provably determine the rational points.
For $\delta = 35$, we have no such luck. The genus $5$ hyperelliptic curve has rational points at infinity on it, and the Jacobian of the corresponding genus $2$ curve has rank $2$. It is unclear to me how to proceed in the $\delta = 35$ case.
